# Asterisk - what does "make menuconfig" command do?

Tags: asterisk

I wonder what ***make menuconfig*** command is used for and what I can actually change by using it? Unfortunatelly I didn't find any manual/config guide in the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command allow you remove some modules and compile limited set of features.

Also it allow see which modules can be compiled, and allow change some compile time option

You require libcurses-devel for that command.

If you are not expert, only reason you may need it is enabled mysql module in addons section.